# How can I send data from a ViewController to a Static TableView inside a ContainerView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I wanna know **how I can send data from the "ListOfCountries ViewController" to "PhoneInputData TableViewController"** (included in a Container in another different ViewController [the pic shows the detail of the relationship]):

[image]

*Note: The process is this in the app --> Click on the cell "Your country & Code" from the PhoneInputData TableViewController, and then the app shows the list of countries with the respective dial code. Then I choose one option from this tableView and this is showed in the previous "PhoneInputData TableViewController" as your selected option.*

**Do I need to create a new file for the cell? How can I use the segue from "ListOfCountries ViewController" to "PhoneInputData TableViewController"?**

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you can hold the reference of tableview in the view controller

Comment: Use delegate pattern create a protocol for ListOfCountriesViewController implement it in PhoneInputDataTableViewController assign itself as delegate in prepare for segue method and before dismissing ListOfCountriesViewController call that delegate method.